# Is there any way to don't perform any action on Vuex until state is ready

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am performning a fetch inside an action on the created step of one of my components. The problem comes when I need some parameters that comes from my state to do the fetch, because when I reload the page the state comes with the default values instead of the values that have previous reload. If I add a "delay" that works, but impatc on the page performance in a critical point. Is there any way to wait until state is ready before do any action? Thanks in advance. My code is something like this

```
state = {
myParams: null
}

        async ({ state, commit, dispatch, getters, rootState: { route }, rootGetters  }) => {
        
        await axios.post(myURL, {
    data: {
    myParams: state.myParams,
    }
    }
        }
```

Comment: 1. Could you share what you'd tried?
2. Did you try Promises?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be enough to call the api in the created lifecycle and define the parameters necessary for calling the api in the component created lifecycle.

When the api call is completed by adding a loading component, it would be neat to remove the loading component and render the data.